# Finding images in RAM dump

Tags: fft, data-mining, cross-correlation, computer-forensics

### Extracting screenshots from RAM dumps

Some classical security / hacking challenges include having to analyze the dump of the physical RAM of a system. [volatility](http://www.volatilityfoundation.org/) does a great job at extracting useful information, including wire-view of the windows displayed at the time (using the command [*screenshot*](https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility/wiki/Command%20Reference%20Gui#screenshot)). But I would like to go further and find the actual content of the windows.

So I'd like to reformulate the problem as finding raw images (think matrix of pixels) in a large file. If I can do this, I hope to find the content of the windows, at least partially.

My idea was to rely on the fact that a row of pixels is similar to the next one. If I find a large enough number of lines of the same size, then I let the user fiddle around with an interactive tool and see if it decodes to something interesting.

For this, I would compute a kind of spectrogram. More precise a [heatmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map) where the shade show how likely it is for the block of data #*x* to be part of an image of width *y* bytes, with *x* and *y* the axis of the spectrogram. Then I'd just have to look for horizontal lines in it. (See the examples below.)

The problem I have right now is to find a method to compute that "kind of spectrogram" accurately and quickly. As an order of magnitude, I would like to be able to find images of width 2048 in RGBA (8192 bytes per row) in a 4GB file in a few minutes. That means processing a few tens of MB per second.

I tried using FFT and autocorrelation, but they do not show the kind of accuracy I'm after.

### The problem with FFT

Since finding the length of a mostly repeating pattern looks like finding a frequency, I tried to use a Fourier transform with 1 byte = 1 sample and plot the absolute value of the spectrum.

But the main problem is the period resolution. Since I'm interested in finding the period of the signal (the byte length of a row of pixels), I want to plot the spectrogram with period length on the *y* axis, not the frequency. But the way the discrete Fourier transform work is that it computes the frequencies multiple of *1/n* (for *n* data points). Which gives me a very low resolution for large periods and a higher-than-needed resolution for short periods.

Here is a spectrogram computed with this method on a 144x90 RGB BMP file. We expect a peak at an offset 432. The window size for the FFT was 4320 bytes.

[image: Spectrogram with FFT]

And the segment plot of the first block of data.

[image: Segment plot of FFT first block]

I calculated that if I need to distinguish between periods *k* and *k+1*, then I need a window size of roughly *k²*. So for 8192 bytes, that makes the FFT window about 16MB. Which would be way too slow.

So the FFT computes too much information I don't need and not enough information I would need. But given a reasonable window size, it usually show a sharp peak at about the right period.

### The problem with autocorrelation

The other method I tried is to use a kind of discrete autocorrelation to plot the spectrogram.

More exactly, what I compute is the cross-correlation between a block of data and half of it. And only compute it for the offsets where the small block is fully inside the large block. The size of the large block has to be twice larger than the max period to plot.

Here is an example of spectrogram computed with this method on the same image as before.

[image: Spectrogram using correlation]

And the segment plot of the autocorrelation of the first block of data.

[image: Segment plot of the autocorrelation of first block]

Altough it produces just the right amount of data, the value of the autocorrelation change slowly, thus not making a sharp peak for the right period.

### Question

Is there a way to get both a sharp peak and around the correct period and enough precision around the large periods? Either by tweaking the afformentioned algorithms or by using a completely different one.

Comment: You will never be able to retrieve the screenshot of the current window from the RAM, except if you dump the video card's RAM and read at the correct location. So in my opinion, forget about that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't judge much about the FFT part. From the title ("Finding images in RAM dump") it seems you are trying to solve a bigger problem and FFT is only a part of it, so let me answer on those parts where I have some knowledge.

> analyze the RAM dump of a system

This sounds much like physical RAM. If an application takes a screenshot, that screenshot is in virtual RAM. This results in two problems:

a) the screenshot may be incomplete, because parts of it are paged out to disk

b) you need to perform a physical address to virtual address mapping in order to bring the bytes of the screenshot into correct order

> find raw images from the memory dump

To me, the definition of what a raw image is is unclear. Any application storing an image will use an image file format. Storing only the data makes the screenshot useless.

In order to perform an FFT on the data, you should probably know whether it uses 24 bit per pixel or 32 bit per pixel.

> I hope to find a screenshot or the content of the current windows

This would require an application that takes screenshots. You can of course hope. I can't judge about the likeliness of that.

> rely on the fact that a row of pixels is similar to the next one

You probably hope to find some black on white text. For that, the assumption may be ok. If the user is viewing his holiday pictures, this may be different.

Also note that many values in a PC are 32 bit (Integer, Float) and 0x00000000 is a very common value. Your algorithm may detect this.

> images of width 2048

Is this just a guess? Or would you finally brute-force all common screen sizes?

> in RGBA

Why RGBA? A screenshot typically does not have transparency.

---

With all of the above, I wonder whether it wouldn't be more efficient to search for image signatures like JPEG, BMP or PNG headers in the dump and then analyze those headers and simply get the picture from the metadata.

Note that this has been done before, e.g. WinDbg has some commands in the *ext* debugger extension which is loaded by default

```
!findgifs
!findjpegs
!findjpgs
!findpngs
```

Comment: the current window's screenshot is in the video's card memory, where a pixel is rgba(8)

Comment: @user1952009: graphic cards have their own RAM. IMHO the graphic card RAM is not necessarily in PC RAM, even with DMA.

Comment: That's exactly what I said (and you can dump the allocated graphic memory of the process you are in, so you can dump the whole (allocated) graphic memory when you are in the kernel)

Comment: @user1952009: I'm the top 2 answerer of the windbg tag (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/windbg/topusers, look for Thomas Weller) but I don't know how to do that. Do you have a reference to a tutorial or description on how that's done?

Comment: For OpenGL I thought there would be a function but I didn't find it. It is probably hidden somewhere in https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL). For the other low-level graphic libs it should be quite the same. For win32 GDI it should be something like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144871(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: `GetDC()` is a method that you can call while the OS is running. You can't call it on a dump file.

Comment: Yes I know. For dumping really the graphic card I don't know, and I don't really care. Maybe doing a segfault in the driver will provoke a dump ? :)

Comment: Now I'm totally confused. Do you have a dump or don't you? If you don't care about dumping the graphics card content, what else do you dump then? You also know that a kernel dump may not contain the information. Still you are looking for bitmaps somewhere, but where?

Comment: @user1952009: oh, sorry, I just realize that you're not the OP.

Comment: A segfault will not help on Windows. It will be handled by the OS and the OS will generate a bluescreen, dumping the kernel memory, not the video card memory.

Comment: @Thomas I edited the intro of the question to clarify what I mean with "raw images", I also mentioned volatility. It's not about finding files, but pixel matrices. I'm interested in whatever is in the dump, if some windows aren't in RAM, then they're not, and I move on. No, I don't actually need to know if the images are 24 or 32 bits per pixels. If I do an FFT on bytes, it will just show an additional peak for a period of 3 or 4 bytes. Just like I don't need to know the screen width, I only need an upper bound, the FFT will find the image width.